# "Second order correct", "first order asymptotics"

Tags: convergence, asymptotics, stochastic-ordering

I keep seeing phrases like "first order asymptotic", "second order correct", "high order asymptotics" and I am honestly don't know how these terms are rigorously/conventionally/informally defined.  My best guess is that the higher the order, the higher the level of precision.  I'd like to know some sort of definition or guidance for how these terms are used though.

A Few Examples:

1. I see two different asymptotic approximations for a distribution/probability under different assumptions.  There are several terms in these results and the first terms match.  I then see that the first set of assumptions are "second order correct" under the second set of assumptions.  I am assuming they are doing something like Edgeworth expansion and just matching the first couple of terms. But why call this first and second order?  Is there a more detailed reason to call this first and second order beside it just being the first few terms?
2. I see a derivation for error for a given estimator.  This estimator has several sources of error.  One source is called first-order bias, and another is called second-order bias.  I am assuming it has to deal with how fast these biases converge to zero?  Meaning one is at a slower rate and one is at a faster?  But why call it first and second?  Is it just comparing the two sources together, the worse one being first and the better one being second? Or is it something about the rate and both of these could have been first-order biases?

Comment: It depends on the context.  Could you supply some?

Comment: Added some examples.

Comment: Typically these terms will apply to powers in some kind of series expansion. e.g. you might see a series in powers of $n^{-\frac12}$ in some contexts.

Comment: I definitely see things like $n^{-1/2}$ and also $o(n^{-1/2})$ and $O(n^{-1/2})$